# OnClick event on Custom legends Chart.js / Angular 5

Tags: chart.js, angular5

I'm working on a project using Angular 5 and Chart.js.
I needed to create custom legends into my charts so I follow this git issue to help me a bit: [Github Issue Chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2565).

It was very helpful and It worked as expected only with pure javascript, but trying to reply the example into Angular 5 App just doesn't work, it throws me ***this.updateDataset() is not a function***.
Here is a snippet of what I'm currently doing into the **options** [object of Chart.js library](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends):

```
legendCallback: (chart) => {
        const legendHtml = [];
        legendHtml.push('<table>');
        legendHtml.push('<tr>');
        for (let i=0; i<chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
            const color    = chart.data.datasets[i].borderColor;
            const legendId = 'linear-d'+i;
            legendHtml.push(
                '<td onclick="this.updateDataset(event,' + '\'' + chart.legend.legendItems[i].datasetIndex + '\'' + ', ' + '\'' + legendId + '\'' + ')">' +
                '<div id="'+legendId+'-square" style="background-color:' + color +'; border: 2px solid ' + color +'; width: 15px; height: 15px;"></div>' +
                '</td>'
            );
            if (chart.data.datasets[i].label) {
                legendHtml.push('<td id="'+legendId+'-text" style="cursor: default; font-size: 12px;" onclick="this.updateDataset(event,' + '\'' + chart.legend.legendItems[i].datasetIndex + '\'' + ', ' + '\'' + legendId + '\'' + ')">' + chart.data.datasets[i].label + '</td>');
            }
        }
        legendHtml.push('</tr>');
        legendHtml.push('</table>');
        return legendHtml.join("");
    },
```

So the important part is this one `'<td onclick="this.updateDataset(event,' + '\'' + chart.legend.legendItems[i].datasetIndex + '\'' + ', ' + '\'' + legendId + '\'' + ')">'` where the **onclick** is trying to call **this.updateDataset()**.

How should I call the function **updateDataset()** into the *onclick* event of the element or how should I declare the function so I could access to it from the *onclick* event.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a neat solution but it's the only one I found so far.
Instead of using the onclick event I added an **eventListener** after adding the new legend. Then you need to do minor changes to the **updateDataset()** function.

The **legendCallback** should look something like this:

```
legendCallback: (chart) => {
      var legendHtml = [];
      legendHtml.push('<table>');
      legendHtml.push('<tr>');
      for (var i=0; i<chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
          legendHtml.push('<td><div class="chart-legend" style="background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[i].backgroundColor + '"></div></td>');                    
          if (chart.data.datasets[i].label) {
              legendHtml.push('<td class="chart-legend-label-text" id="' + chart.id + '_' + chart.legend.legendItems[i].datasetIndex + '">' + chart.data.datasets[i].label + '</td>');
          }
      }                                                                                  
      legendHtml.push('</tr>');                                                          
      legendHtml.push('</table>');
      return legendHtml.join("");                                                        
    },
```

And then add the listener and the **updateDataset()** function after the declaration of the Chart:

```
document.getElementById("customLegend" + this.chartId).innerHTML = myChart.generateLegend();
var legenTags = document.getElementsByClassName("chart-legend-label-text");
var updateDataset = function(e) {
  var id = e.currentTarget.id;
  var index = id.split('_')[1];
  var chartId= id.split('_')[0];
  if (myChart.id == chartId) {
    var meta = myChart.getDatasetMeta(index);
    // See controller.isDatasetVisible comment
    meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null? !myChart.data.datasets[index].hidden : null;

    // We hid a dataset ... rerender the chart
    myChart.update();
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < legenTags.length; i++) {
  legenTags[i].addEventListener('click', updateDataset, false);
}
```

I hope it helps.
If anyone has a better solution please share.